# reverse bitwise operations in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to reverse a bitwise operation but I'm unable to since & cannot be reversed, kindly help

```
((n << d) & 0xff) | (n >> (8 - d))
```

I tried this code below but it doesn't seem to work

```
def lrot(n, d):
    return ((n >> d) & 0xff) | (n << (8 - d))
```

Comment: You're not "reversing" `& 0xff`, though. Not clear what this function is supposed to return, anyways

Comment: @OneCricketeer the original function returns 8-bit cyclic bit-shift left (see example in my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

See function `rot_right` for a function which does an 8-bit cyclic bit-shift right, the opposite of the function in your original code:

```py
def rot_left(n, d):
    return ((n << d) & 0xff) | (n >> (8 - d))


def rot_right(n, d):
    return ((n << (8 - d)) & 0xff) | (n >> d)

n = 23
d = 2

print("n: {:08b}".format(n))
print("rot_left(): {:08b}".format(rot_left(n, d)))
print("rot_right(): {:08b}".format(rot_right(n, d)))
print("rot_right(rot_left()): {:08b}".format(rot_right(rot_left(n, d), d)))
```

Output:

```
n: 00010111
rot_left(): 01011100
rot_right(): 11000101
rot_right(rot_left()): 00010111
```

Comment: actually i recognize my mistake, that worked ,thank you